# Can you write a lot of @ directives like assembly, import, template without emitting template output in T4?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4

I am modifying a T4 Template and it has a gross effect of generating a lot of blank lines at the top of my output (a .cs file), due to the following .ttinclude which my .tt file includes, which imports a lot of assemblies, like this, each closing #> tag is going out of macro scope and back to literal template text scope:

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="True" debug="True" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE"  #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Configuration" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Windows.Forms" #>
<#@ assembly name="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" #>  
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" #>  
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Common" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Globalization" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Configuration" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Windows.Forms" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating" #>
<#+
#pragma warning disable 0162
```

I count 22 lines of stupid whitespace injected into my output .cs file by the above. I tried combining the assembly and import statements into one `<#@ #>` section but that doesn't "compile", T4 dies without any error:

```
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" 
    assembly name="System.Core.dll" #>
```

Note that the following works:

```
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" assembly name="System.Core.dll" #>
```

So I have a choice of UNREADABLE DIRECTIVE LISTS or UNREADABLE TEMPLATE OUTPUT full of empty whitelines.

Isn't there another way?  This counts among the most annoying flaws I have ever seen in a templating/preprocessor tool.

Comment: Is there any whitespace after the `#>` parts?

Comment: It's the newline not the whitespace, that is causing this.  If this was a C preprocessor #define argument, the preprocessor would have consumed the newline. As it is, T4 emits  the newlines after each `<#@ #>` but it requires a maximum of one @ directive per `<# #>` section which is among the lamest things I have ever seen.

Comment: I didn't notice such behavior in my templates, although I certainly don't use that many directives. I think T4 is supposed to strip a newline after a `<#@ #>` directive unless there's additional whitespace before the newline, but I may be wrong here.

Comment: Anyway the code you posted contains whitespace after both `FirebirdClient` directives. Remove it and check if it changes something.

Comment: Removing the spaces still leaves 20+ blank lines, which are I believe by design for T4.  I believe that what should be done here is to move all this into a new .NET assembly and make the T4 template-include simpler.

Comment: Thats absolutely not by design. Sounds like a bug has crept in somewhere.  Raise a connect issue?

Comment: Working a bit more, the even more annoying issue is that any syntax errors in a .tt file that includes a .ttinclude reports wrong line numbers. I believe these two issues are related.